# VPN certificate installation checking ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate, vpn

Is it possible to check  whether a particular VPN certificate is installed on an ios device in  objective c?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: I have been searching. But didnt get an answer.